# Grid Search with custom metrics in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cross-validation, grid-search

I use Keras (Python) for a CNN model and have a custom call back function to calculate metrics such as a precision, recall etc. I have given the function below. This function works fine for a single call of a fit function and returns correct metric values at epoch end. However, I am trying K-Fold cross validation with the GridSearchCV function and would like to have the custom metrics returned for each of the Folds and also when I use grid_result.grid_scores_ to get the mean/std across K-Folds.  This doesn’t work.

Also, is it possible to get the metrics calculated for a separate validation data.

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

class CustomMetrics(Callback):

def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.validation_f1 = []
    self.validation_recall = []
    self.validation_precision = []

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    # Extracting the second column since the activation is softmax
    predicted_prob = self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])[:,1]
    true_y = self.validation_data[1][:,1]

    threshold = optimal_cutoff_PRC(true_y,predicted_prob)
    convert_to_01 = lambda x: 1 if x > threshold else 0
    vfunc = numpy.vectorize(convert_to_01)
    test_predicted_01 = vfunc(predicted_prob)         

    _val_f1 = f1_score(true_y, test_predicted_01)
    _val_recall = recall_score(true_y, test_predicted_01)
    _val_precision = precision_score(true_y, test_predicted_01)

    self.validation_f1.append(_val_f1)
    self.validation_recall.append(_val_recall)
    self.validation_precision.append(_val_precision)
    print " — val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f — val_recall %f" %(_val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall)
    return

    custom_metrics = CustomMetrics()
```

The following call works fine on the above function:

```
model.fit(timeseries_train, y_train, batch_size = 512, epochs=2, callbacks = [custom_metrics]   , validation_data= val_data)
```

However, this doesn’t work fine with GridSearchCV function defined as follows:

```
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_cnn_model,batch_size = 512, epochs=1, verbose=1)
learning_rate = [0.001]
cnn_filters = [64]
cnn_kernel_size = [5]
param_grid = dict(learning_rate=learning_rate,cnn_filters=cnn_filters,cnn_kernel_size=cnn_kernel_size)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, fit_params =    dict(callbacks=[ custom_metrics]),n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(timeseries_train, y_train,validation_data = val_data)
param_grid

grid_result.grid_scores_ only
```

The above command returns the accuracy which is the regular metric and doesn't return any of the custom metrics:

```
[mean: 0.99428, std: 0.00019, params: {'cnn_kernel_size': 5, 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'cnn_filters': 64}]
```

It neither returns the custom metrics for the K-fold or the additional validation data passed.

Comment: Because you are accessing the metrics of the grid_search object, not the keras estimator.

Comment: Thanks Vivke, Could you provide any tips on how to access the keras estimator?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to access all the folds data, thats not possible. You can only access the estimator which was fitted on whole data with the best params found during cv. That can be done using `grid_result.best_estimator_`. If you want to access all the metrics during the cv, you need to pass a valid metric to the scorer param of the grid_search.

Comment: Also, if your scikit version is 0.19 or above, then its better to pass the fit params in the fit() method of the gridSearch like: `grid.fit(timeseries_train, y_train,validation_data = val_data, callbacks = [custom_metrics])`

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I am not just looking for the best params metrics, I am looking to calculate the precision and recall for every fold and also on the hold out validation data set for every iteration of the K-Fold

Comment: So then the values you are printing in the `on_epoch_end` method are not being printed?

Comment: Yes...there are not getting printed. They are printed if I make a single call to fit but not when I call it with Grid Search

Comment: Have you tried passing the fit_params to the fit() method of gridSearch as I suggested above>

Comment: Yes...it is working fine as I moved it from GridSearchCV to fit method...thank you so much...I am hoping to parse the log and extract the metrics for each CV